# Resize UICollectionViewCell according to iPhone model

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm looking for a smart way to resize UICollectionViewCells. I'm using it horizontally and make the cell almost fullscreen. I thought that the cell at some point resizes itself so that it suits the different screen sizes, or that one is able to set settings for that in IB somehow but apparently you can't.

I then wanted to query for the device type via `[UIDevice currentDevice]....` and just use if statements to make it do things I want but apparently there is nothing like `heightForCellAtIndexPath` like there is for `UITableView`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Really bums me out :/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Size of items in Collection view are prepared in CollectionViewLayout class, so the easiest way to do this is...create a delegate method in layout class to get size of cell from your view controller.